SDL huge memory leaks
I found a huge memory leak in the initialisation of SDL. So I wrote a basic code to test SDL:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur lors de l'initialisation de SDL : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

And here's the end of the valgrind report:
==95625== LEAK SUMMARY:
==95625==    definitely lost: 132,000 bytes in 7 blocks
==95625==    indirectly lost: 71,333 bytes in 960 blocks
==95625==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==95625==    still reachable: 321,975 bytes in 3,253 blocks
==95625==         suppressed: 65,600 bytes in 3 blocks

I asked a friend to try it on his computer and he had 0 memory leak.
If I understood correctly, it's a valgrind error but on my friend's computer there's no memory leak.
I also noticed others have had the same issue , however with less than 50 bytes but mine seems to be unique with a 130000 byte memory leak

For what it's worth, you can create suppression files for valgrind to suppress these intentional leaks.

SDL has many different backends and selects one appropriate to the individual system at hand; it's not surprising for its behavior to differ between machines. It's also not surprising for it to allocate enough memory to store two full display buffers, and to hold it through the end of execution. A leak is only a problem if the amount of memory grows over your program's runtime, or if the memory should be released. You haven't demonstrated either of those things here.

@CharlesDuffy: Re “It's also not surprising for it to allocate enough memory to store two full display buffers, and to hold it through the end of execution”: This does not explain why Valgrind would report memory as “definitely lost.” If the program does not have a pointer to the memory, then not only is it unable to free it later, but it cannot make any use of it during program execution. So memory that is “definitely lost” seems to be either an error in the program or a failure of Valgrind to find a pointer to the memory that the program actually has. Neither of the duplicates explain this.

@EricPostpischil, yes, on SDL_Quit one could conceivably deallocate those buffers, but why bother? The program is about to shut down anyhow, and the OS will reclaim everything. Sure, it's a bug, but it's one of the most unimportant "why should anybody care?" bugs I can think of.

@CharlesDuffy: The issue is not whether SDL_Quit should free the memory. (It should, because a client program may call it earlier than the end of the program and want the resources free.) The issues is that Valgrind says the memory is permanently lost. If that is true, neither SDL nor the rest of the program can use the buffers for any productive purpose, because the pointer(s) to them were lost.

I'm still hard pressed to see why that's a practical problem. Memory doesn't get returned to the OS until exit -- even if it were freed it would be returned to a pool for malloc to reuse within the same process. Sure, there's a theoretical case for a program that might allocate additional memory after its GUI is shut down, but a practical case would be a new one on me.
